# WebRTC DTLS-SRTP OpenSSL Server Handshake Failure

Tags: c++, openssl, webrtc, wireshark, dtls

***Here is my procedure in OpenSSL Server Mode,***

**Initialization Part of  SSL and BIO variables:**

```
map<int, SSL> m_SSLMap;
map<int, BIO> m_BioWriteMap;
map<int, BIO> m_BioReadMap;
int InitializeServerNegotiationMode(int iFd)
{
        SSL *pServSslFd;
        BIO *pWb, *pRb;

        pServSslFd = SSL_new(m_pCtx);
        assert(pServSslFd);

        if ( SSL_version(pServSslFd) == DTLS1_VERSION)
        {
            pWb = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
            pRb = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
            assert(pWb);
            assert(pRb);
            SSL_set_bio(pServSslFd, pRb, pWb);
            SSL_set_accept_state(pServSslFd);
        }
        m_SSLMap[iFd] = *pServSslFd;
        m_BioReadMap[iFd] = *pRb;
        m_BioWriteMap[iFd] = *pWb;

        return INITIALIZATION_SUCCESS;
 }
```

**Server Mode Negotiation Operations when DTLS data comes to the server:**

```
int ServerModeDTLSNegotiation(int iChannel, const char *pBuff, const int iLen, int iFd)
{

    SSL *pServSslFd;
    BIO *pRbio;
    BIO *pWbio;
    pServSslFd = &m_SSLMap[iFd];
    pRbio = &m_BioReadMap[iFd];
    pWbio = &m_BioWriteMap[iFd];


    char buff[4096];
    memset(buff, 0, strlen(buff));

    BIO_write(pRbio, pBuff, iLen);

    if(!SSL_is_init_finished(pServSslFd))
    {
        int iRet = SSL_do_handshake(pServSslFd);
    }

    int iNewLen = BIO_read(pWbio, buff, 2048);
    if(iNewLen>0)
    {
        char *pNewData = new char[iNewLen+1];
        for(int i=0;i<iNewLen;i++)
        pNewData[i] = buff[i];
         m_pEventHandler->SendReply(iChannel, (unsigned char *)pNewData, iNewLen);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("[DTLS]:: HandShaking Response failed for this data, 
         return -1;
    }
    return NEGOTIATION_SUCCESS;

}
```

Here I am attaching Wireshark TCP-Dump for better monitoring about the issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/quidcs6gilnvt2o/WebRTC%20DTLS%20Handshake%20Failure.pcapng?dl=0

Now, I am confident about my initialization of SSL_CTX variable. Because, Sometimes Handshake successfully negotiate for every port. But sometimes Handshake fails for one or two port. I am working for 5 days to solve WebRTC DTLS Server Mode Negotiation for Google Chrome. But I haven't found the root cause for this problem.

Comment: Would appreciate if you can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627063/clarification-needed-on-openssl-api-in-implementing-dtls-1-2-server)

Comment: Do you have to call SSL_do_handshake(pServSslFd);  in server mode? I think that before a handshake, the server should imply, or you should check if handshake is completed, and conclude that the data is part of a handshake message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link for **TCP-Dump** is not working. 
Anyway, it seems your solution should work.

As it's a server program, it's definitely **multi threaded**. But it's really dangerous to **initialize SSL variables** or to **perform handshake procedure** without **locking**. In that case so many things can happen if these two methods are processed by multiple thread.

My suggestion is to add **locking mechanism** for these methods.

Comment: Actually, I solved this a long time ago. And yes, you are right. I solved this problem adding mutex lock.

Comment: @Light Yagami, Can you please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627063/clarification-needed-on-openssl-api-in-implementing-dtls-1-2-server)